# How to access text of an HTML element using Kanna

Tags: swift, html-parsing

Given HTML of the following form (generated outside of my control), how would I extract the text *'What I wanted'* using [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna)?

```
<div class="entry-meta">
    \n\t\t\t<p>
        <span class="tags-links">
            <a href="http://example.com" rel="tag">This is not</a>
        </span>
    </p>
    What I wanted\t\t
</div>\n
```

(The `\n`s and `\t`s are there in the original source, so are included here only for completeness - I can remove them using `.trimmingCharacters(in:)`)

Given I have an `XMLElement` representing that `div` node (nodes are `XMLElement`s in Kanna, regardless of source data type), I've tried various ways of extracting the text *'What I wanted'*, but both `.text` and `.content` return *'This is not What I wanted'*.

I was previously using Hpple, but it's not as Swifty and requires a lot more work to use. Given a reference to the same node, Hpple would yield the expected text via `(node.children.last as! TFHppleElement).content`, but looking into the source of Kanna, it looks like `.content` and `.text` both return the result of `libxmlGetNodeContent(nodePtr)`

Is there another approach that I'm missing, or is this a shortcoming in Kanna?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kanna lets you select nodes using XPath expressions, and the node you want is the 2nd text-node child in that `div` element, so you should be able to get it with this:

```
divElement.xpath("text()[2]")
```

Comment: `text()` was a gap in my XPath knowledge, so thanks! It doesn't want/need the leading `/` though.

Comment: Glad it helped (and edited the answer to drop the leading slash)